# Azure Logic Apps On-premises data gateway doesn't allow executing native SQL queries

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I tried to execute a SQL query using Azure "On-Premises data gateway" from Azure Logic Apps. Running the logic resulted the following error message:

> { "status": 400,   "message": "Gateway GetPassThroughNativeQueryMetadataAsync - this operation (Execute Native SQL) is currently not supported using an on-prem gateway connection\r\nclientRequestId: ...", "source": "sql-scus.azconn-scus.p.azurewebsites.net" }

[image]

There should be something wrong with my setup. If not, what's the point of having "Execute a SQL Query" if there is no support for native SQL queries? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/):

> SQL native query is not supported for on-premises SQL server.

So this feature is not available at this point.

Comment: You could add a vote at the following link. Doesn't seem to be making much progress.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Support-quot-Execute-a-SQL-query-quot-action-through-an-on/idi-p/69514